# Quickly Maintain/edit 100+ WordPress Forms on multiple websites

Tags: forms, maintenance, workflow

Does anybody know a solution or smarttrick to maintain lets say 100+ forms on wordpress websites from 1 main location. So lets say i have 500 websites with the exact same contact form and i would like to add 1 field to all of them at the same time it would take me 10 minutes instead of a complete day.

Comment: You can work out what the change would be in SQL and then run the same SQL on every database? (Assuming the IDs are the same, or can be easily queried for, and you can connect directly to every database from one place.)

Comment: You could create this form as a plugin. As soon as it gets updated, it will reflect on all websites that are using it.